# How to change username authentication to email authentication in already buit project?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I initially used to login using username and password but now want to change it to email address authentication in the same site without having to delete the existing users and content.
I made the following changes in my files but get an error 'UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username'

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
```

views.py

```
class UserFormView(View):

    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'main/registration_form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)

            # cleaned (normalized) data
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            # return user objects if credentials are correct
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

            if user is not None:

                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    # request.user.username       display their username
                    return redirect('main:register2')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

class LoginForm(View):

    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'main/login_form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        if error:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form}, 
{'error': error})
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            # Correct password, and the user is marked "active"
            auth.login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/main/home/")
        else:
            # Show an error page
            error = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/main/", {'error': error})
```

The errors i got - http://dpaste.com/0ZVHW0P

Please answer considering the fact that I am new to django.
Thanking you in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, even if you want to use the email address as the identifier, you must still use the `username` field in the auth table if you want to use Django's auth framework 'out the box'.

What is happening above is that you're not setting username, which means you have empty usernames in your `auth_user` table. Since username **must** be unique, the moment you try to add a second user without a username, you get a database level integrity constraint `UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username`.

To fix this, change your `views.py` to look like the following:

```
class UserFormView(View):

    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'main/registration_form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)

            # cleaned (normalized) data
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.username = email
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            # return user objects if credentials are correct
            user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)

            if user is not None:

                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    # request.user.username       display their username
                    return redirect('main:register2')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

class LoginForm(View):

    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'main/login_form.html'
```